# How to store data in a JSON file?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting the data from my JSON file through this code:

```
var content = await rootBundle.loadString("json/story1.json");
decodedContent = json.decode(content);
```

And I would like to be able to store an integer inside the `story1.json` file.

Comment: You can't write to an asset. They are read only. You could update a shared preference of the same name, or update the story and write it to a local file.

Comment: In addition to @RichardHeap, you can use `dart:io` commands to manipulate your text file. Also checkout: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json